# Is there a way to annotate a deployconfig with timestamp?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In short, I'm trying to add an annotation with the actual time.

***cmd line should like (or not) :***

```
oc annotate --overwrite dc webtest Last_Jmeter_test='timestamp'
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a way .

```
 node ('master'){
  stage("date") {
        date = sh(
            script: """
            date
            """,
            returnStdout: true
        )
        echo "${date}"
    }
}
```

this is by using jenkins .

```
oc annotate --overwrite dc webtest Last_Jmeter_test='${date}'
```